# How to optimize project with Require.js to produce only ONE Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, optimization, requirejs

I managed to use require.js and it's optimizer to optimize my project. But **it generates 3 javascript files:**

**1. main file**

The require.js config file (the one referenced in html as *data-main* )

**2. require.js library**

The code for require.js.

**3. My application code**

Is it possible to merge these 3 javascript files into one single file?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the grunt js project, with specific to :

```
   grunt concat
```

and the plugin for require js:

https://github.com/asciidisco/grunt-requirejs